# is there a way to debug my code if it gets stuck in giving responses after a point

Tags: csv, ip, rate-limiting, proxies

I encountered an issue while running my code; it successfully generated around 7000 records but then became unresponsive, failing to produce the remaining outputs. Despite attempting to address the problem with proxies, the issue persisted. I'm now exploring alternative methods to debug the code effectively.